# The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: windows-phone-7

I try to download file

```
    ...
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(link));
        request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetData), request);
    }

    private void GetData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
      HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
    ...
```

, but "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."
I download other files from other server with this code. 
I can open this link on PC and WP7.

Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is clear to anyone who reads it.. Click on the link, forbidden access. If you cannot access it, how is our code supposed to access it? You either need to give it permission on the server, or if a cookie is required, use it in your HTTPRequest.

Comment: Okay, well make sure that this is not where your program is seeing its error.